# Specified python version in dockerfile not reflecting in the container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python-django web app that I want to run in a docker container. I am using MySql for my database, so I need to use mysqlclient, which does not work for python 3.10 and above when installing using pip, so I am using python 3.9. The following is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.13
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

And the `docker-compose.yaml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

When running with `docker-compose up` everything gets created as expected, except for the python version, which when I check from the containers terminal tells me it is running 3.10.8. I tried using other images of python 3.9 from https://hub.docker.com/_/python, but still, I get the same result. Thus I cannot run my Django project there because mysqlclient cannot get installed with pip3.10 and above.

The interesting thing is, I have the exact same dockerfile using a flask application, and that container works as I expect it to.

Is something missing here?

EDIT:

For clarification, the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml` is located at the django projects root directory, if that matters.

Comment: Still dunno what the issue is, but I just created a new folder and passed in `python:3.9` to the `Dockerfile` and it worked. But still, I would like to know why it would fail like this.

Comment: Do you run `docker build` in the same directory as the Dockerfile? and if so, would you share the exact command you use to build the image?

Comment: I use `docker-compose up --build` where my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml` are located. I think there was something funky going with the specified python version, because when I placed the version as `python:3.9` is started to work, so I guess there might have been some problems pulling the image or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `FROM python:3.9` instead of `FROM python:3.9.13` seems to solve the issue. Still not sure why it would go and take python 3.10+. Guess there might have been some problems pulling the image and it defaulted to something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).